# Installing jQuery Plugins - Best Practices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Just getting started with using jQuery plugins.
Most examples (via youtube, blogs etc) show the script being inserted into the html doc directly (see code below as an example). Is this the best way to do it? Seems like keeping everything seperate would be the best way.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancy_title").lettering();
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
    </script>
```

Comment: well, what you're doing is right... what else do you want?

Comment: Just wanna confirm that it's OK to add jquery/javascript directly into the html doc. Or is it generally better to link to an external js doc.

Comment: You want to link to an external doc as often as possible since it separates concerns--Easier to maintain--and the main page will load quicker because it's a smaller response size when taking the script code out of there, with script content in a separate smaller files as well (which can be made even smaller using minification).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to keep put your global scripts first, then ones that might inherit or over-ride them go below/after them.

Many people put CSS in the `head` section so it loads right away, and the JS files at the end of the `body` tag so the page can load before the javascript does.

Best practice is to keep in mind the order of execution, which is from top to bottom, from loading to rendering a page to the user. And keeping things organized, like anything else.

Comment: Cool thanks. Ya I understand the basics of the DOM. Just a bit confused about jquery and plugins because I'm new to it.